# Does it reflect worse on a student to skip class or not go to any office hours?

Tags: attendance, office-hours

Does it reflect worse on a student to skip class or not go to any office hours? My professors so far think it's better for one to never show up to ask questions but go to classes but I disagree because classes aren't always useful. Sometimes my professors read right out of the book for the entire lecture and I don't need someone to read for me.

Comment: If you ace the exams, then both are OK: you obviously do not need the lectures and you do not need the office hours.  Is that your situation?

Answer (score 4):

I would try to look at it from the other side of the desk. Your professor probably:

- Does not think the lectures are useless, and
- Feels that most of your questions were answered in class.

I am sure you disagree, but that's how your professor will see it.

So in terms of how skipping class and attending office hours reflects on you -- well, I am sure they find it obnoxious. By the way, if you skip both class and office hours, then they won't know you at all, which is only marginally better than being actively disliked.

At any rate, if you are the only student attending office hours, then it would be difficult to justify refusing to help you (assuming you are respectful, etc.). If there is a crowd at office hours, however, it would be reasonable to favor those students who attended the lecture.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't attend class or go to office hours, you're effectively saying you don't need the professor to teach you. If this is indeed true for you, then more power to you. The professor might at most be mildly annoyed by how you're not coming to class if you continue to ace the exams.

Two caveats:

1. If you never come to class, the professor will have no impression of you beyond what you write in the homework & exams. You can't really ask them for a recommendation letter because they won't have much to write about.
2. More importantly, most of the time, students who don't come to class do worse - much worse. In fact I'm pretty sure there's a strong correlation between how often a student comes to class and how well they do.

Feel free to not go to class if you're confident, but if you start having trouble with the homework / mid-terms, it's time to attend.